# l2ping Bluetooth connection maximum links

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hci

I have a question regarding the max concurrent connections using bluetooth dongles. My system is based on 10 Raspberry Pi-es 2 and what I am trying to accomplish is to make a bluetooth low energy connection between them for some research project. My bluetooth dongles are: Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode). When I set up Raspberries for the bluetooth mode (Bluez, etc.) everything works fine and every raspberry can scan other raspberries (hcitool scan), but when I try ping other raspberries from one of them I only succeed to get response from 7 devices, where the rest of the devices report "Error: connect error: Too many links". I am wondering is this hardware related limitations or technology limitations, since I've read in a few articles that Bluetooth when making a piconet supports only 8 devices. Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, I think I just answered my question here:
Classic Bluetooth active nodes: 7

http://www.glynstore.com/content/docs/bluegiga/BLE_getting_started.pdf

Comment: BLE doesn't have the same connection limit as regular Bluetooth.  It's completely dependent on the manufacturer how many concurrent connections they want to support.  I have a dongle that only supports 3.  I have another that seems to support more than 7 but then goes wonky after more than 7 (data stops flowing on some of the connections).  The error you get varies between dongles too.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. Yes, I realised that a few days ago.

Comment: @TimTisdall .... Hi Tim, I have one question regarding the BLE. Is there a way to get a response from BLE device (such as ping response) similar to l2ping in classic Bluetooth. For example, between 2 raspberries with BLE dongles ?

Comment: I don't know.  You should post another question, but state what you're trying to do not just "is there l2ping for BLE".  "Yes" or "no" won't help much.